# Optimizing a stored function call in SELECT and WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I have an SQL query with the following structure:

```
SELECT *, storedfunc(param, table.field) as f 
FROM table 
WHERE storedfunc(param, table.field) < value 
ORDER BY storedfunc(param, table.field);
```

Is there a way to optimize this eliminating several function calls? Or does MySQL perform such optimization behind the scene? In fact the function is declared as deterministic.

I need also to mention that the function params are partially from selected table's columns. I changed the example slightly to reflect this.

Comment: Is `param` a column in the table or a parameter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rewrite and test which one performs faster:

```
SELECT *, storedfunc(param, table.column) AS f 
FROM table 
WHERE storedfunc(param, table.column) < value 
ORDER BY f ;

SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT *, storedfunc(param, table.column) AS f 
    FROM table 
  ) AS tmp
WHERE f < value 
ORDER BY f ;
```

In MySQL, you can even write like this (**warning: not standard SQL** syntax):

```
SELECT *, storedfunc(param, table.column) AS f 
FROM table 
HAVING f < value 
ORDER BY f ;
```

Comment: Strangely, I tried the later but MySQL showed an error. Will try again.

Comment: Can you post exactly what you tried? And what the error message was?

Comment: In fact, I tried f in `where` clause, not in `having`, this is why it produced the error. Anyway, does MySQL peerform the optimization automatically, due to `deterministic` function declaration?

Comment: Not sure, have to test that. And it probably depends on the version of MySQL. Newer versions have better chances to be performing the optimization.