# Does calling a user defined function twice in select query lead to inefficiency?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have a simple table where people's birthday are been stored. I also have a simple scalar user defined function where the function takes a "Date" object (birthday) and returns an int (Age). I wrote a query which tries to select every entry that has an age of 17.

In the "select" query, "`dbo.calculateAge(Birthday)`" were written twice, so I was just wondering, does this mean that "`calculateAge`" function will be called twice? Does this leads to inefficiency? If yes, is there a better way to write this query?

My Query:

[image]

My Table:

[image]

I choose not to include implementation of the "calculateAge" function here because I don't think it is useful to the question I'm asking.

Comment: It may not be called twice, but because you are calling a function on the `Birthday` column, this will render all indices on that column not usable in MySQL.  I think not being able to use the index is more significant than whether the engine has to call the function once or twice.

Comment: You may also take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977607/optimizing-a-stored-function-call-in-select-and-where-clauses

Comment: The *code format* & *Result* window looks like it belong to `Sql Server`. But you have tagged `Mysql`

Comment: Since this old question has unresolved clarification queries waiting, it can probably be put on hold as "unclear".

Answer (score 1):

> does this mean that "calculateAge" function will be called twice?

No, just once. But to be sure, make sure your function is declared as deterministic.

> Does this leads to inefficiency?

No.

> If yes, is there a better way to write this query?

It's fine.